# jQuery submission trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following function to perform some easy validation on a pure radio group survey form:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked)').val()) {
        this.reportValidity();
        return;
    }
    this.submit();
});
```

I started from this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6s4j0qt/) to and slightly modified it.

This works when validating radio buttons very well and as desired... but for some reason the form will no longer submit once every radio group has a selection, unlike the version in the fiddle.  I feel like I am missing something pretty simple and will face palm once someone answers this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your JS works fine as far as I can tell (tested in the fiddle you provided). The problem is most likely somewhere else.

Comment: @Sty the fiddle isn't the code that is not working.  Sorry about that confusion.  The code only works insofar as it checks to be sure a radio group has at least one selected.

Comment: Should have clarified, I tested the code you provided in this post by copy pasting it in the fiddle.

Comment: @Sty I did too and it only correctly validates, BUT! doesn't allow actual submission

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your modified script, you're checking for ANY unchecked radio button, so the check is always exiting -- only one in a group can be checked, so you're bound to have at least one that isn't.  It won't flash up a validity check because the group is fine, but it'll still return out of the submit function without getting to the actual submit() call.

Comment: hmmm, that does make sense.  Let me mess with the code a bit and get back to you

Comment: Have fun with it!  :-)

Comment: I have verified that this is why it is not submitting.  I haven't been able to modify my code to properly submit, but I did verify the correctness of this answer awhile ago.

Comment: I tinkered with the jsfiddle you referenced -- it's a bit clumsy, but may do what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/q6s4j0qt/18/

Comment: that fiddle is treating your javascript weird (handling that last if statement incorrectly) but moving it into {} or moving it down a line makes it work correctly.  I actually ended up doing this though a few hours ago: jsfiddle.net/q6s4j0qt/19 ... yours looks bettter....

Comment: Far better if you can figure it out yourself though -- congrats!